# HTML E mail Code Broken In G mail, Y ahoo, Aol, etc., etc

Tags: html, email, templates

So I've tried to follow along with many video tutorials & training, but EVERYONE seems to be wrong about what email service providers are allowing through their pre-processors. Everything is being broken & most of the CSS even inline isn't getting thru to display properly, especially in Gmail. Here's what I'm working with:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin:0px; padding:0px;
font-family:'Arial Black';
background-color:gold;
}

h1{
margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color:gold;">

<div style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:auto; border:2px solid black; max-width:600px; background-color:gray;" width="100%">
<center>
<img src="http://producerhookup.com/NewsLetters/NewsLetter3/images/Header.jpg" style="max-width:600px; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="100%"/>
<h1 style=" margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; color:white; font-family:'Arial Black'; font-size:30px;">
Drumma Boy Sound Kit Vol.1!!!
</h1>
<img src="http://producerhookup.com/NewsLetters/NewsLetter3/images/DrummaBoyDrumKit.png" style="max-width:300px; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="100%"/>
</center>

<p style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:10px; color:white;">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p><br>

<p style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:10px; color:white;">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p><br>


<center>
<img src="http://producerhookup.com/NewsLetters/NewsLetter3/images/FooterBar.jpg" style="max-width:600px; margin:0px; padding:0px;" width="100%"/>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing to get this HTMl Email Template through & displaying properly? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and what I mean by "being broken" or "NOT displaying properly" means that divs & tables are being spaced out (too many gaps) & fonts aren't being displayed with chosen fonts, only Gmail's default. Inline code isn't working regardless of what I've tried. There must be some hidden insights to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using post as a reply, but i cannot access comments through mobile version of SO app.

So first of all you should read
https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/rendering-engines/

Then notice that HTML in email is heavy and can be treated like potential danger. So it's better to use normal text messages. Better for you and clients email memory

Main issue, as it is said in the link, is fact you cannot include the head tag in the email. It can cause some errors, or can just not be interpreted.

Should I quote everything from that site?